# Your order could not be processed error when using a test account

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am trying to test the in-app billing in my app.
I tried using the static codes google provide, and it works perfectly fine. Now I want to raise the level and check with a test account. I've added a test account to my developer account and when the test account tries buying the content (the item is shown) it tells :`Your order could not be processed. Please try again`. I've registered this test account several days ago, and still nothing.

Did anyone encounter this problem and know hows to solve it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot buy your own apps. 
http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=141659

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that your app is signed with the release key.
Also, if you uploaded an APK to your Console just to enable in-app products (it's not published), make sure that your testing application has the same android:versionCode.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue today, and yes this is as per Google's policy to not let people buy their own apps using the same account that you used in the Google Play Developer Console.

To get around this:

1. Go to the settings of your Android device
2. Go to accounts Go to Google accounts
3. Remove the Google account that you used in the Google Play Developer Console
4. Add a new/secondary Google account (if you dont' have a second Google account, you will have to create one first).
5. Add your payment method for this Google account (i.e. credit card)
6. Go to Google Play store and buy your app!
7. Re-add your original Google account in settings -> accounts.

I wanted to experience things the way the user does when they download and install my app, so it was important to me to go through the same process.